# I would like a proxy server that "forwards" to two development servers

Tags: google-app-engine, networking, proxy, sproutcore

**Summary:**

All development is on my local machine. I have two development servers running on my machine. I would like to use these development servers as if they were one. What is the simplest way to do this?

**Details**

I have two development servers. One server is the [Sproutcore](http://sproutcore.com) development server (holds the application, css, images, whatever). The other server is the [App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) development server (holds the data). The app engine server has a finite number of ways that it can be accessed. Both of these development servers are running on separate ports on my machine.

Lets say I have a regular expression called X that specifies all the url paths that can be used to access the app engine server.

I would like a proxy server that will forward all http request paths matching X to the App Engine server, and all non matching paths to the Sproutcore server.

> Example:
>
> If my proxy server is *localhost:8080*
>
> And my app engine server is *localhost:8081*
>
> And my sproutcore server is *localhost:8082*
>
> And I have a regular expression that matches "/dogs/_the_dogs_id" (where _the_dogs_id is a integer)

If I make a request of *localhost:8080/js/application.js* I would expect that to go to the sproutcore server (because it does **not** match the regular expression)

If I make a request of *localhost:8080/dogs/7* I would expect that to go to the app engine server (because it does match the regular expression)

As near as my (the client) request is concerned, I am only asking localhost:8080 for all these resources. The proxy server is silently forwarding them to the correct destination. Preserving the request type, the data, the headers, etc. I just need it to forward it based on the url request path.

Is there any simple way to set up such a proxy server? It would be immensly useful for web development.

Thank you

Comment: This isn't a programming question; it's a web server configuration question. Voting to move to [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm curious - how do you plan to run this app once it's deployed?

Comment: why don't you move the Sproutcore part under a static folder served by the App Engine http server?

Comment: In production, the Sproutcore derived files would be served as static files by App Engine. This proxy configuration would only be useful when using the development server. The development server does not do a full "compilation" of static files, it (appears) to just serve the raw javascript I write. That is, it serves the files verbatim (checking for changes every time), it does not "bundle" them into a single large file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, upon further investigation, it turns out that Sproutcore comes with built in functionality to do this exact thing. Just really impressive how they think of these thinks ahead of time. Adding a proxy to a particular route is as easy as adding the following lines below the "# SET UP PROXY" comment (In your Buildfile)

```
# ===========================================================================
# Project: Todos
# ===========================================================================

# Add initial buildfile information here
config :all, :required => :sproutcore

# SET UP PROXY
proxy "/task", :to => "localhost:8000"
proxy "/tasks", :to => "localhost:8000"
```

Really could not be much simpler. I also like this a great deal because it is a portable solution. This contrast to solutions requiring another depency (eg. Apache).

Answer (score 0):

`mod_rewrite` FTW

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

> This module uses a rule-based
>   rewriting engine (based on a
>   regular-expression parser) to rewrite
>   requested URLs on the fly

You define a regular expression that matches a URL, and then re-writes it to where you want to re-direct the request to.

Also, to clarify, the mechanism you are describing is called a "Reverse Proxy": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy

-tjw

Comment: Thanks you. Yes, I was fairly sure that I was not using the word "proxy" correctly. :)

I am sure the Apache idea would work, but I am completely unfamiliar with it. Setting up Apache seems to be a non-trivial task. Thank you for the thought though.

Comment: Setting up apache is actually extremely easy.